# Magento 2: How to load data by Page using same collection object again?

Tags: magento2, collection

I am using `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` and loading data by creating objects.

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',  array('simple', 'configurable'))
                    ->setPageSize($limit)
                    ->setCurPage(1);
$result = $collection->getData();
```

The `$result` contains the first-page result. Can I use the same object to render the second-page result?.

Comment: change setCurPage(1) to setCurPage(2) and check what results you are getting..

Comment: It returns the previous data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collection data can be reset by using `clear` function in `$collection` and then changing the page will provide next page data.

The following code might be helpful.

```
 $limit = 10;
 $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',  array('simple', 'configurable'))
     ->setPageSize($limit)
     ->setCurPage(1);
 $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
 $page = 1;
 while ($page <= $pages) {
     $collection->clear();
     $collection->setCurPage($page);
     $result = $collection->getData();
     $page++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the `clear()`.